# how to avoid different version using different packages in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I wanted to import the plugins: 
`location_picker: ^0.0.12`
`location: ^1.2.0`

But I got this error: `Android dependency 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7' has different version for the compile (26.1.0) and runtime (27.1.1) classpath.`

How do i solve this?

Comment: did [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14020) not work ?

Comment: Seems to be a common error lately. It was mentioned about 12h ago and yesterday in the Flutter Gitter channel with a workaround.